# Can't fetch all fields from Instagram graph API media node

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Some fields work as they should, fields like `media_type`, `id` and `permalink`.

But if I try to fetch `timestamp`, `owner` or `username` I get an error message:

```
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Please read documentation for supported fields.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "HYYvmdnqQIh"
  }
```

Nothing in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media/) says that there should be any restrictions for these field.

My API call looks like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{HASHTAG ID}/recent_media?user_id={USER ID}&fields=id,media_type,media_url,caption,permalink,timestamp,username,owner&access_token={ACCESS TOKEN}
```

Comment: You are looking at the wrong part of the documentation - the endpoint you are reading from is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media, and there it explicitly lists which fields you can ask for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get timestamp, username and others for hashtag media, you can only get more details for your media, for other public content you can only get very basic info about media.

These are the data you can get for hashtag media:

- caption
- comments_count
- id
- like_count
- media_type
- media_url
- permalink

Here is link to hashtag [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/recent-media)